# Problema al generar Pdf - Apache Cordova

Tags: apache

Hola amigos estoy tratando de convertir un html que tengo una carpeta de mi proyecto a pdf con cordova-pdf pero no puedo lograr hacerlo: Aca mi codigo

```js
function generarPdf(){
    const before = Date.now();

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => {
      console.log('DEVICE READY FIRED AFTER', (Date.now() - before), 'ms');
     
      var file = './../template/pdf.html'
    
      cordova.plugins.pdf.fromURL(file,{
        documentSize: "A4",
        landscape: "portrait",
        type: "share"
      }),
        (sucess) => console.log('sucess: ', sucess),
        (error) => console.log('error:', error);
    });
  }
```

Comment: podrias agregar mas detalles como si te sale algun error ?

Comment: no me sale ningun error, solo que el pdf sale vacion no se si sera problema de la ruta (path)